# outofbound exception while adding to array

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this class its basically a university system on which a student can post different kind of posts and people can reply to there posts.

Event is a kind of post

```
public class Event extends Post {
    private String Venue;
    private String Date;
    private int Capacity;
    private int AttendeeCount;
    String[] Attendee_list=new String[getCapacity()]


    public Event(String Id,String Title,String desc,String CreatorID,String Venue, String Date, int Capacity)
    {
        //ID i.e eventID and CreatorID are auto created
        super(Id,Title,desc,CreatorID);
        this.Venue=Venue;
        this.Date=Date;
        this.Capacity=Capacity;
        AttendeeCount=0;
    }
```

i am trying to implement this method.

where reply.getResponderID() basically gets responder id of reply on post.

when i am trying to add the responder it to the attendee list of the event after it passes the if() condition it is throwing an arrayindexoutofbound exception.

```
    @Override
    public boolean handleReply(Reply reply)
    {
            if (AttendeeCount < Capacity & !(Arrays.asList(Attendee_list).contains(reply.getResponderID())))
            {
                Attendee_list[AttendeeCount]=reply.getResponderID();
                getReplyCollection().add(reply);
                AttendeeCount++;
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

I can't figure out why???

Comment: Time to use your debugger to find out why your program is misbehaving

Comment: A clue: AttendeeCount is greater than or equal to what getCapacity() returned.

Comment: Put this `this.Attendee_list = new String[getCapacity()];` as the last line in your constructor. Otherwise it will be initialized before `this.Capacity` is set (and still has default value `0`). [Instance fields are initialized sooner than constructor](https://farenda.com/java/java-initialization-order/).

Comment: Check the size of the array.

Comment: Also, java naming conventions have classes begin with capital letters, and methods and variables beginning with lower case letters. This makes identifiers easier to identify when debugging.

Comment: Also, why is this question closed as duplicate? This is clearly not answered by [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it).

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek thanks ```this.Attendee_list = new String[getCapacity()];``` solved my problem